# How do I round a number in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

How do I round a number in Groovy? I would like to keep 2 decimal places.

For example (pseudo-code):

```
round(1.2334695) = 1.23
round(1.2686589) = 1.27
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use:

```
Math.round(x * 100) / 100
```

If `x` is a `BigDecimal` (the [default](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Math) in Groovy), this will be exact.

Comment: Make sure to assign your variable to the result of this expression - example:

x = Math.round(x * 100) / 100

Comment: not groovy, this is Java and should be avoided at all times.

Comment: The other `.round()` answers wouldn't work for me as I'm dealing with a BigDecimal. This answer worked as expected to round a BigDecimal to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 54):

If you're dealing with doubles or floats

You can **simply** use

```
assert xyz == 1.789
xyz.round(1) == 1.8
xyz.round(2) == 1.79
```

Comment: @J.J.Bocanegra because 0 is an `int` so you need to cast it `0d.round(2)`

Answer (score 19):

Use mixin.

```
class Rounding {
    public BigDecimal round(int n) {
        return setScale(n, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    }
}
```

Add this to your startup class and round() is a first-class method of BigDecimal:

```
BigDecimal.mixin Rounding
```

Test cases:

```
assert (new BigDecimal("1.27")) == (new BigDecimal("1.2686589").round(2))
assert (1.2686589).round(2) == 1.27
assert (1.2334695).round(2) == 1.23
```

Comment: This is heavily dangerous, mixin scope is the whole JVM, we got an obscure problem in production when an implicit call to setScale by a toString method resulted in the class name declaring the mixin as output in place of the numeric value (com.xxx.ClassName.Rounding@13b4f2ee ) Probably a classLoading problem as groovy script are loaded dynamically . Java 6

Answer (score 14):

Like this:

```
def f = 1.2334695;
println new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(f);
```

Or like this:

```
println f.round (new MathContext(3));
```

Output:

> 1.23

Reference: [Formatting a Decimal Number](http://langref.org/groovy/numbers/output/format-a-decimal-number)

Comment: MathContext(3) specifies total precision of 3 numerals so e.g. 12.34 would become 12.3 or 123.45 would become 123

Answer (score 14):

Groovy adds a `round()` method to the `Double` and `Float` classes, so:

```
(123.456789f).round(2) == 123.46f
```

Source: [Rounding Numbers in Groovy](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/01/groovy-goodness-round-and-truncate.html)

Answer (score 5):

Probably, more **Groovysh** way would be to use this snippet `(x as double).round(2)` like this:

```
def a = 5.2355434
println "a = $a, a.class = ${a.getClass()}"

def b = (a as double).round(2)
println "b = $b, b.class = ${b.getClass()}"
```

Comment: Not if you are using groovy's `default decimal numeric` BigDecimal because when you cast that double back to a BigDecimal it get's ugly.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at @sjtai's and @cdeszaq's answers you don't need to get mixed up with mixin if you just define a method like this:

```
def bigDecimalRound(n,decimals){
    return(n.setScale(decimals, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP))
}
```

It is the `BigDecimal` builtin method `setScale` that performs the rounding.

```
println(1.2334695.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP))
>> 1.23
```

It's worth noting also that setScale accepts negative arguments in order to round things to larger order of magnitude, i.e.

```
println(123.2334695.setScale(-1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP))
>> 1.2E+2
```

Answer (score 2):

Working from @sjtai's great answer, this is the Mixin I use for just about all my decimal rounding needs:

```
class Rounding {
    public BigDecimal round(int decimalPlaces = 0, RoundingMode roundingMode = RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN) {
        return setScale(decimalPlaces, roundingMode);
    }
}
```

If rounds to an `int` by default, and uses an "even" rounding method (reducing statistical error by default is always a good thing), but it still allows the caller to easily override these.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
def rd = 1.3425345352
sd = ((float)rd).round(3)

println sd  

>> 1.343
```

Answer (score 1):

as simple as this:

```
YOUR_NUMBER = 1.234567
((int) YOUR_NUMBER * 100)/100
```

note: this would cut off the extra decimal points; it doesn't round up.

Comment: It rounds up if you start with a negative number... That's not rounding tho it's truncating towards 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is surprisingly complex for Groovy. It's usually... groovier.

You need to create a MathContext object to do the rounding.

```java
num =  9.59123331333g
// rounds to 2 places, rounding up by default
mc = new java.math.MathContext(2)
num.round(mc)

==> Result: 7.0
```

with help from

- https://blogs.oracle.com/fadevrel/rounding-numbers-and-decimal-places-in-numerical-fields
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#round(java.math.MathContext)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert any number to *float* and then use the `round()` function as:
`((float)1.2334695).round(2)`